# Local variable to global variable

Tags: c++, c++14, jsoncpp

I'm very new to C++ so sorry if I'm making a really stupid mistake.

I'm using JsonCPP to try read my config file and I wanted to store them in a global variable, but I can't seem to work out how to do it without it clearing as soon as the function ends.

main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    bool b = InitJson();
    if (!b) {
        std::cout << "Config file missing or deformed.";
        std::cin.get();

        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Username: " << *bUsername << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

json.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

bool InitJson()
{
    std::ifstream config_file("config.json");
    Json::Value config;
    config_file >> config;

    if (!config["Username"] || !config["Password"])
        return false;

    bUsername = new std::string(config["Username"].asString());
    bPassword = new std::string(config["Password"].asString());

    if (!config["AutoMessage"] || !config["AutoMessage"]["enabled"]) {
        bMessageEnabled = new bool(false);
    }
    else {
        bMessageEnabled = new bool(config["AutoMessage"]["enabled"].asBool());
        bMessageDelay = new int(config["AutoMessage"]["delay"].asInt());
    }

    std::cout << "Config file loaded sucessfully." << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

header.h:

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <iostream>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <fstream>

static std::string* bUsername;
static std::string* bPassword;

static bool* bMessageEnabled;
static int* bMessageDelay;

bool InitJson();
```

Thanks for any help, and sorry again if I'm being a total idiot

Comment: Try to avoid using global variables...

Comment: Totally unrelated: Rethink A) The use of globals (anyone can mess with a global at any time, making tracking what's really going on in a program unnecessarily difficult (that said, there's a good case for a `const` global because once initialized no one can mess with it)). B) static globals in a header (Every file that includes the header will have a different instance. So much for shared configuration information). C) The use of pointers. No need for dynamic allocations here.

Comment: `if (!config["AutoMessage"] || !config["AutoMessage"]["enabled"])` should use `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: There's no good reason for your global variables to be pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving them in static variables you could save the values in its own class. One way to access that class would be to make it a singleton. This would allow you to access it like a global variable.
You could also give that object to every object which needs the settings saved in there.

Comment: This answer won't be helpful to C++ newbies (like the OP) unless you show how to do it with code.